quickFix seqNum reset situations
my program is using 1.14.3 quickFix lib. My configuration does not set ResetOnLogon/ResetOnLogout/ResetOnDisconnect. I know that user could make use of HTTP command interface of quickFix to reset seqNum. Other than these, what other situations can cause my program to reset seqNum?

Counterparty sends you 141=Y on their Logon for example.

This question seems unfocused. Are you having an actual issue that you are trying to resolve?
